# How to use a while loop to start at the right end of the list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

So I have a list of numbers that I want to increment only when a condition is met. In this case, the list contains the numbers 0-9.

What I want to do is change 9's in my list to 0's and if the next element isn't a 9, add one until it is = 9. Eventually it should be a list of zeros.

this is what I have so far:

```
def increment(self):
    i = len(self.number) - 1
    while (self.number[i] == 9):
        self.number[i] = 0
        i -= 1
```

It changes the last element in the list number, which is 9, to 0. But I'm lost on how to check to see if 8 is = 9 and if it isn't, add 1 until it is. Same goes for all the other numbers.

How can I iterate starting from the last element of my list with a while loop?

Comment: What is `self`? Can you show the scope of the class?

Comment: Also, please explain the concept behind "add one until it is nine" when you could just set it directly to nine...

Comment: And by the way, to iterate in reverse order you just use `for item in reversed(somelist)`

Comment: FYI you can reference the last element of a list using [-1] (or the last nth element of a list with [-n]).

Comment: @cricket_007. Self is irrelevant in this case. I just copied and pasted my code. Self.number is a list from created in another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to change the last number in `self.numbers` which is not `0`: if it is `9`, change it to `0`; otherwise increment it by `1`. You can do:

```
def increment(self):
    for i, num in enumerate(reversed(self.numbers)):
        if num:  # that is, if num is not 0
            self.numbers[-i - 1] = 0 if num == 9 else num + 1
            break  # once one number is changed, we stop
```

Demo:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = list(range(1, 10))

    def increment(self):
        for i, num in enumerate(reversed(self.numbers)):
            if num:
                self.numbers[-i - 1] = 0 if num == 9 else num + 1
                break

demo = Demo()
for _ in range(5):
    print(demo.numbers)
    demo.increment()
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # the original list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0]
```

Comment: what I want the function to do is go through each element in the list that I provided, check to see if it's a 9, change it to 0 if it is, then check the next element to see if that's a 9. if not, add one until it is 9 and then change it to zero.  My list consists of ints 0-9. Going in reverse order would change the last element to 0 and then move on to 8, it would then need to add one and move on to the next element which is 7. Then it would need to add 2 to make it 9 and so forth.

Comment: @Omar So if I understand correctly, if `self.numbers` starts as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 9]`, then after `increment` is called *once*, it should become `[0, 2, 3, 4, 0]`, right? (This is what my code does.) Or should it become `[0, 9, 9, 9, 0]`? Or `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`?

Comment: it starts at [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], then it becomes [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0], then [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0]----> [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,0,0]---->[1,2,3,4,5,6,9,0,0] and so forth

Comment: @Omar Yeah, I know, but just for example. What should the list be after one call to `increment`?

Comment: @Omar I see. So nobody got it right because we didn't know this is what you want. I'll try again.

Comment: My bad. Now that I think of it, I should've said my desired output. Wasn't sure if that would be ok when I posted this. And thank you for trying.

Comment: @Omar Wait, are you sure that after [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,0], it should be [1,2,3,4,5,6,*8*,0,0], not [1,2,3,4,5,6,*7*,0,0]?

Comment: I'm sure. While your method does work for my given, for whatever reason I can't implement into my code so I'll need to make some adjustments.

Comment: @Omar But you also said that after [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], it should become [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,**8**,0], not [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,**9**,0]. I'm confused. Is the list supposed to increment like a number, or not? While I'm glad that you accepted my answer, I really want my code to do the right thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are iterating through the list and want to start from the last to first you can take the list, reverse it, then iterate.

```
my_num = [1,2,3]
rev_num = my_num.reverse()
for num in rev_num:
    print num
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
def increment(self):
    i = len(self.number) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        while(self.number[i] < 9):
            self.number[i] += 1
        self.number[i] = 0
        i -= 1
```

Comment: this produces the same result as my function, the last element is changed to 0 but all the other elements are still the same.

Comment: That does work. hmm. So there's an issue with my code. That's fine. Your solution makes sense and works. Thank you.